# How does supercharging work?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

It reads that I can "touch the plane with a second finger to supercharge my weapon", but touching the screen with second finger doesn't seem to do anything (at least visually I can't tell the difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to collect the 9. card called "Main Weapon Supercharge" before being able to use the "Supercharge" feature.

Take a look at this video at 1:12 to see what the card looks like: